# How to read integers from a text file without using hasNextInt() Java

Tags: java

So I'm new to programming and we have to do this lab where we read from a text file that has only one line with numbers. We then have to put those integers into an array. I know how to read the numbers when they are in separate lines but not when they are in one line. I also know how to put numbers into an array, so I don't need help with that.

The only methods we are allowed to use are:

- `hasMoreTokens()`
- `hasMoreLines()`
- `readDouble()`
- `readInt()`
- `readLine()`
- `readToken()`

Is there a way to do such while using only these methods?

Here is the code:

```
import chn.util.FileInput;
import chn.util.FileOutput;

public class Compact {
    public Compact (FileInput inFile, FileOutput outFile){
        int[] compactArray = new int [21];
        int numZeroes = 0;
        int num;
        int length = compactArray.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { //making the array for the integers in the list
        compactArray[i] = 0;
    }

    while (inFile.hasMoreLines()) {
        num = 0;
        num = inFile.readInt(); //reads the integers per line
        compactArray[num]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(compactArray[i] == 0) {
            length--;

            for(int j = i; j < length; j++) {
                compactArray[j] = compactArray[j+1];
            }
            i--; // Decrement i to check the value that was shifted
        } else { 
            numZeroes++;
        }
    }

    // now print the array without 0
    for(int i = 0; i < numZeroes; i++) {
        outFile.print(" " + compactArray[i]);
    }

    outFile.close();
}
```

For some reason it's simply returning a string of zeroes. I was thinking it may have to do with the way I read the code.

Comment: what's wrong with `readInt()`?

Comment: Please don't ask us to do your homework for you. We'll just try to find out which school you go to and we'll inform your teacher. Try to solve the problem yourself, and ask us if you're stuck with some particular point. Please read [ask].

Comment: Oh. I'm not asking for homework. And I'm from Del Norte High School :) You can inform my teacher. I just wanted to know if there was a way I can read all integers in a line. @EngineerDollery

Comment: @JonnyHenly can readInt() read all the integers in a line? and separate them?

Comment: @EngineerDollery The real assignment is to remove all the zeroes in a line but I already know how to increment and decrement position values to do that. But I think the way I'm reading my integers is the problem. Sorry if I offended you!

Comment: I'm not offended. It's a policy of this site not to do people's homework for them, because they learn nothing if we do, and that's what it looked like from your description. Having users moderate the site and post messages is also one of the site's policies. My comment wasn't meant to be rude, but we write perhaps hundreds of these a month, so we keep them short and to the point.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Oh yes I completely understand! A lot of people try to cheat on their homework! Don't worry, I was just curious if there was a way and I couldn't ask my teacher because it is Thanksgiving Break. Thank you for the info!

Comment: It is also very customary to post a meaningful code snippet on which you are working. That way, it's easier to identify where a problem occurs. That way you often also get additional advice (for example outdated things that people find in old tutorials).

Comment: @amenthes Okay! I will edit the post to add the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Input:** *numbers_line.txt* which has one line: 
**1 8 3 43 4 56**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List; 

public class ReadIntFromFile {

     public static void main(String []args){
        String fileName = "numbers_line.txt";
        List<String> numbersArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                numbersArrayList = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] numbersStringArray = new String[numbersArrayList.size()];
        numbersStringArray = numbersArrayList.toArray(numbersStringArray);
        int[] numbersIntArray = new int[numbersStringArray.length];
        for(int i = 0;i < numbersStringArray.length;i++) {
            numbersIntArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbersStringArray[i]);
        }

        for(int x : numbersIntArray)
             System.out.println(x);
     }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
8
3
43
4
56
```

Comment: We aren't allowed to use try catch (didn't learn it yet). I added the code I used up there :)